# Dynamic Data: How to enable-disable row editing dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have Asp.net application that implemented with Dynamic Data technology.
All data from my database is displayed in DetailsView (standard for dynamic data).
Each row in DetailsView  contains icon with buttons edit and delete.
In some cases I should disable row editing and hide edit-delete buttons in some rows.
Is it possible in dynamics.

P.S. I have found `DetailsView.AutoGenerateEditButton` property, but it does not applicable for me: the property just hide edit-delete button for all grid, not for some rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RowDataBound` event.

Have a look at this article about [Custom Formatting Based Upon Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288030.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.</br> Problem is resolved. Your topic was very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Visible='<%# DecideHere((int)Eval("ID")) %>' Text="Edit" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected bool DecideHere(int id)
{
    return id % 2 == 0;
}
```

(this works for me in GridView, and I'm sure something similar will work for you in DetailsView)

Comment: The method is being invocated on `DataBind()`